# JPA foreign key without entity

Tags: jpa

I'm trying to create a favorites table between a user and a business, but I don't want to use the entire entity, just the ids, how can this be done in JPA? Something like this:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "favorite", schema = "public" , uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id", "business_id"})
})
public class Favorite {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "appuser_id")
  @NotNull
  private UUID appuser_id;

  @Column(name = "business_id")
  @NotNull
  private Long businessId;
}
```

instead of:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "favorite", schema = "public" , uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"user_id", "business_id"})
})
public class Favorite {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "appuser_id", referencedColumnName="id")
  private AppUser appUser;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "business_id", referencedColumnName="id")
  private Business business;
}
```

Problem is, solution #1 has no foreign key ref of any kind, is there a way to do this? I would really prefer my result objects to only have ids and not the entire user / business entities every time.

I know I can make a dto with ids only and manually set it up / workaround, but I'd like an answer to this problem if one exists.

Comment: Your first solution is ok. What's not working?

Comment: Solution 1 is just a field, it's not a foreign key / linked in any way by jpa.

Comment: It's really astounding that there is no easy solution to this very common issue